# Updating a jQuery Mobile checkbox (with GWT)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, gwt, checkbox

I'm using jQuery Mobile enhanced GWT and have a checkbox. But when I set the GWT checkbox using a normal *check.setValue(false);* it sets the value, but does not change the jQM enhanced display.

I have tried various combinations of refresh and prop/attr but they all seem to either do nothing at all or fail with a message saying it's not initialised.

The code is various variants of `$('input[name="gwt-debug-cwCheckBoxMonday"]').prop("checked", true).checkboxradio('refresh');`

I gout it to work using `$("input[type='checkbox']").checkboxradio("refresh");` but I want to only do it for a specific one, not every one.

I made a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/liftarn/38uch/ to illustrate the problem.

The HTML is from http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCheckBox

Comment: you fiddle had several mistakes, here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/38uch/6/

Comment: @ezanker Yes, I know. It wasn't ment to be runnign code but a base for work. While your fiddle works I noticed you cheated a bit when you rewrote it. For instance you used knowledge of things that are unknown at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit tricky. First you have to get the input element. One way to do it is (where w is your CheckBox):

```
NodeList<Element> nl = w.getElement().getElementsByTagName("input");
Element e = nl.getItem(0);
```

Now you have the input element and can get the id using *getId()*

Then you just make a native function taking the id and the boolean value and do

```
$wnd.$("#" + id).prop("checked", false).checkboxradio("refresh");
```